# Extract the list of running IP's from AWS

Tags: python, python-2.x, boto3

I need to exactract a list of all Running IP's from AWS and along the list of IP i also want the tag-value & the region-name(or availability-zone). The list should look as follows

```
ex : [[('23.1.1.141', ' Production LB', 'us-east-1'), ('47.2.14.93', 'sung2-cloud-trial01-LBi-b89671', 'us-west-2'),................]]
```

The list consists of the following:

```
<'Running IP'>,<'Tag-value'>,<AvailabilityZone>
```

Using `boto3` and I can achieve this using `describe_instances()`, so I tried using it as follows:

```
def gather_public_ip():
    regions = ['us-west-2', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1']
    combined_list = []   ##This needs to be returned 
    for region in regions:
        instance_information = {}
        ip_dict = {}
        client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                              region_name=region, )
        instance_dict = client.describe_instances().get('Reservations')
        for instance in instance_dict:
            .....
            #WHAT CODE COMES HERE???

gather_public_ip()
```

So what exactly should i be looking into for this ? I am not sure how to do so, please help

**NEW ANSWER RESPONSE:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nisingh/PycharmProjects/untitled1/more_specific.py", line 35, in <module>
    gather_public_ip()
  File "C:/Users/nisingh/PycharmProjects/untitled1/more_specific.py", line 27, in gather_public_ip
    ipaddress = instance['PublicIpAddress'] # Which one do you need?
KeyError: 'PublicIpAddress'
{u'Monitoring': {u'State': 'disabled'}, u'PublicDnsName': '', u'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', u'State': {u'Code': 80, u'Name': 'stopped'}, u'EbsOptimized': False, u'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 16, 34, 17, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'PrivateIpAddress': '10.11.32.10', u'ProductCodes': [], u'VpcId': 'vpc-8ae766ef', u'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2016-01-29 22:20:18 GMT)', u'InstanceId': 'i-5e8ae8a8', u'ImageId': 'ami-5189a661', u'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-10-11-32-10.us-west-2.compute.internal', u'KeyName': 'pdx01-cump-050215', u'SecurityGroups': [{u'GroupName': 'pdx01-clv-jumpeng', u'GroupId': 'sg-50abbf35'}], u'ClientToken': 'inYin1430584456904', u'SubnetId': 'subnet-57e45b20', u'InstanceType': 't2.micro', u'NetworkInterfaces': [{u'Status': 'in-use', u'MacAddress': '06:91:7c:86:7c:d5', u'SourceDestCheck': True, u'VpcId': 'vpc-8ae766ef', u'Description': 'Primary network interface', u'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-7d566d0b', u'PrivateIpAddresses': [{u'Primary': True, u'PrivateIpAddress': '10.11.32.10'}], u'Attachment': {u'Status': 'attached', u'DeviceIndex': 0, u'DeleteOnTermination': True, u'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-08d40929', u'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 16, 34, 17, tzinfo=tzutc())}, u'Groups': [{u'GroupName': 'pdx01-cloud-dev-jumpeng', u'GroupId': 'sg-50abbf35'}], u'SubnetId': 'subnet-57e45b20', u'OwnerId': '547316675291', u'PrivateIpAddress': '10.11.32.10'}], u'SourceDestCheck': True, u'Placement': {u'Tenancy': 'default', u'GroupName': '', u'AvailabilityZone': 'us-west-2b'}, u'Hypervisor': 'xen', u'BlockDeviceMappings': [{u'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1', u'Ebs': {u'Status': 'attached', u'DeleteOnTermination': True, u'VolumeId': 'vol-0990f21b', u'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 16, 34, 21, tzinfo=tzutc())}}], u'Architecture': 'x86_64', u'StateReason': {u'Message': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown', u'Code': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown'}, u'RootDeviceName': '/dev/sda1', u'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', u'Tags': [{u'Value': 'pdx01-jump02-DEPRECATED', u'Key': 'Name'}, {u'Value': 'Cloud Eng Jump Box', u'Key': 'Description'}], u'AmiLaunchIndex': 0}
```

Comment: What is the content you get in ``instance_dict``?

Comment: @Uzzee it constitutes of all the information in a form of dict , you can see this http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances , this is all there being returned

Comment: You need help figuring out how to extract a value from a `dict`?  Seriously?

Comment: @tripleee i tried to simple extract the content , but i was unable to do so i am expecting a that once i have all the 3 values then i can just 

`combined_result = list(zip(ip_list, tag_list, region_list))
    combined_list.append(combined_result)
 
  return (combined_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is all about finding the information in the response and grabbing it;

```
def gather_public_ip():
    regions = ['us-west-2', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1']
    combined_list = []   ##This needs to be returned 
    for region in regions:
        instance_information = [] # I assume this is a list, not dict
        ip_dict = {}
        client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                              region_name=region, )
        instance_dict = client.describe_instances().get('Reservations')
        for reservation in instance_dict:
            for instance in reservation['Instances']: # This is rather not obvious
                if instance[unicode('State')][unicode('Name')] == 'running':
                    try:
                        ipaddress = instance[unicode('PublicIpAddress')]
                    except:
                        break
                    tagValue = instance[unicode('Tags')][0][unicode('Value')] # 'Tags' is a list, took the first element, you might wanna switch this
                    zone = instances[unicode('Placement')][unicode('AvailabilityZone')]
                    info = ipaddress, tagValue, zone
                    instance_information.append(info)
        combined_list.append(instance_information)
    return combined_list

gather_public_ip()
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, and I also hope you do NOT copy this straight off, but look at how I extracted the info from the return `dict` in the docs.

Comment: okay , so i need the PublicIPAddress, and that cool , also if i can just zip the result as  `combined_result = list(zip(ip_list, tag_list, region_list)) combined_list.append(combined_result) return (combined_list)`

Comment: No need to zip anything, this already stores it as tuples in a nested list of the instances.

Comment: It says '    ipaddress = instance['PublicIpAddress'] 
KeyError: 'PublicIpAddress''

Comment: Can you add a ``print(instance)`` before that line and include the output in your question?

Comment: Updated, please check. also will this be the specific order that i asked for and i am unsure about the unicode `u` charecter

Comment: It still says `KeyError: u'PublicIpAddress'` , with the new code

Comment: I specifically need the 'PublicIP' since they need to be passed to other function . also if you look into the error, it is not having a PublicIPAddress but it does have a private one

Comment: This gets me. Are you using python 2?

Comment: I think thats why, please try the new update if you feel like it, changed it according to https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html, I was using python 3 which handles unicode implicitly, which is why this seems so wierd...

Comment: Actually i cannot do so, the reson being my majority of code runs with 2.7 and i cannot change it

Comment: I did not ask you to change to python 3. I made changes so that you may run it on python 2.7. You can declare unicode strings in python 2 like this ``unicode(string)``

Comment: Well, kinda awkward, but it seems the instance does not have a public ip. Try switching it to private and see what happens! Edit - I added a try/except statement to get the public ip if there is any, and otherwise go with the private.

Comment: on it, so basically i only need the PublicIPAddress , if i can place a condition to check it is in RUNNING state

Comment: KeyError: u'PrivateIpAddress'

Comment: Added your running condition.

Comment: Back at it. It may be that even if it is running it is missing a public ip. I added this try/except catch, please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ip_addr = instance_dict['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['PublicIpAddress']` for IP addresses. `describe_instaces()` response is a dictionary whose value is an array which conatins multiple other dictionaries and so on....